# Hibernate mapping where multiple properties of a class mapping to same class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have Transition table and Property table. 
Transition table has property 'from' and 'to'. Both maps to Property table.
Transition table tells whether transition 'from' to 'to' is allowed or not.

In property table I have Property name and Property type. Where it can be mapped to 'from' or 'to' of a transition entry in transition.

So, Transition and Property are related by manytomany relation.

Please note: Same property entry can be 'from' for some of the transition entries. Also it can be 'to' for other transition entries.

```
Class Transition{
  private Long id;
  Set<Property> from;
  Set<Property> to;
  Boolean isAllowed;
}

Class Property{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private PropertyTypeEnum type;
}
```

Can someone help me with hibernate mapping for this.